Topic: Error Installing Xdebug DLL File in PHP 8.0.2 Environment
Sure! Here's the optimized forum post translated into English, with SEO keywords included for better visibility online:

Topic: Error Installing Xdebug DLL File in PHP 8.0.2 Environment
Problem Description
I am encountering an error when trying to install Xdebug in a Windows environment using PHPStudy Pro WNMP. The error message states that it cannot locate the program entry point gzfwrite in the DLL at d:\phpstudy_pro\Extensions\php\php8.0.2nts\ext\php_xdebug-3.3.2-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll. I have tried various solutions but have yet to succeed, and I'm hoping for some assistance from the community.
Development Environment

PHPStudy Pro
WNMP
VSCode

Request for Help
If any experienced developers can offer a solution to this problem or if anyone has faced a similar issue, please respond to this post. Thank you!
Troubleshooting Steps Attempted

Installing Xdebug

Check PHP version using the command php -v.
Download the corresponding Xdebug extension for the PHP version.
Place the downloaded .dll file in the PHP extension directory.
Configure php.ini by adding Xdebug settings and restart the PHP service.


Issue Resolution

Ensure compatibility between PHP version and Xdebug version.
Verify the architecture of the downloaded DLL file is correct.
Re-download the Xdebug DLL file to ensure it is not corrupted.
Update the zend_extension path in the php.ini file.
Confirm the extension_dir setting is correct and restart the service.




I found a tip on the xdebug website, it states that you need to upgrade the PHP version to at least 8.0.7:

On Windows you need at least PHP 7.4.20 or PHP 8.0.7. Earlier Windows builds of PHP do not export the zlib function gzfwrite which Xdebug 3.1 needs for compression of profile and trace files.

